# "App has stopped" when changing between activities

Tags: android

Hello everyone this is my first android coding and im trying to switch between activities, but i cant simply find where is my mistake.

Main here;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
protected void start()
{
    Intent k= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Try.class);
    startActivity(k);
    finish();
}
```

And My manifest is here and my second activity name is "Try";

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ege.intent.Try"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please, paste the logged error

Comment: Is there an error log? Do you ever call start() with a button or something?

Comment: Yeah sorry, how can i get the logs ?

Answer (score 1):

I think;

May your class package name is wrong but there should be more information about crash.

Change    `android:name="com.example.ege.intent.Try"`
with Try.class location, if it is same in Manifest.
Just try to Change    `android:name=".Try"`

If you put your error or your log details, I can help you

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call `start()`?. Manifest seems okay but check if your package is right, anyway `try` would do the same, `MainActivity` lacks a closing semicolon `}`

Answer (score 0):

the method "start()" is unused.  use it in "onCreate()" method .

you may add a button . swtich activities by listening the click.